# How to sync / update local (volume) data with OpenStack server?

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder, openstack-python-api

I want to create a server within OpenStack nova.
The first step is to create a volume from an image:

```
volume = cinder.volumes.create(5, name="test", imageRef=some_id, ...)
```

The volume will then for some time in the state 'creating'.  Calling `nova.servers.create` with a volume in `creating` state fails:

```
novaclient.exceptions.BadRequest: Block Device f2fe64ee-f049-4a6f-8edd-52579d82fc23 is not bootable. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-f036d084-e9c8-4bdf-b266-73fbbe993796)
```

My idea is to wait until the volume gets `available`:

```
while volume.status != 'available':
    print("Volume status [%s]" % volume.status)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

But it looks that the volume data itself is locally cached and never gets updated - even if the GUI and CLI shows, that the volume is already available.

Is there a (simple) way to synchronize the local data with the remote state? Like:

```
volume.sync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the document called ['Python APIs: The best-kept secret of OpenStack'](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-openstack-pythonapis/):

There is the need to update / get the whole volume again:

```
while volume.status != 'available':
    print("Volume status [%s]" % volume.status)
    time.sleep(1.0)
    volume = cinder.volumes.get(volume.id)
```